# Can I move from Lubuntu to LXLE?

Tags: lubuntu, lts

It looks like there's a new LTS release of Lubuntu coming soon, and I would like to switch to LTS for the stability. While I'm at it, though, I'm curious to try LXLE. Is it possible to make a shift from the current/latest Lubuntu over to LXLE without losing existing apps, settings, themes etc.? Or would it be better to do a clean install?

Also, I couldn't find anything about the release schedule for LXLE. Will there be a new release of it at the same time as the LTS version of Lubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to make a shift from the current/latest Lubuntu over to LXLE without losing existing apps, settings, themes etc.?

In short, no because LXLE makes different choices regarding apps, which in turn affects settings. Take a look at the default [apps](http://wiki.lxle.net/doku.php/programdocs) and this (old) [Q&A](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-significant-difference-between-LXLE-and-Lubuntu-Linux-distributions) to get a better sense of compatibility.

> I couldn't find anything about the release schedule for LXLE.

Here's what the LXLE website says about the release schedule:

> Our development cycle is quite simple. We stick with LTS releases of
>   Ubuntu/Lubuntu. For us, our **new versions of LXLE correspond with the
>   updates provided to the LTS release**. In other words, our versions
>   between LTS releases are the 6 month incremental updates. Example:
>   LXLE 12.04.1,  12.04.2,  12.04.3,  12.04.4,  etc.

But...

> Will there be a new release of it at the same time as the LTS version
>   of Lubuntu?

This is not clear, but based quick research, no. There's a timelapse between Lubuntu and the equivalent LXLE release. For example, Lubuntu [16.4.03](https://lubuntu.me/lubuntu-16-04-3-released/) was released on Aug 03, 2017, while LXLE [16.4.03](http://www.lxle.net/articles/?post=lxle-eclectica-16043-released) was released on Nov 20th, 2017; That's approx. 3 months later.